# Partial Sums of Markov Chain.

Tags: markov-chains, markov-process

Let $X_n$ be a independent identically distributed sequence of integer valued random variables. Suppose $S_n = \sum_{k=1}^n X_k$  with $S_0=0$, and $Z_n = \sum_{j=1}^n S_j$.

Does $(Z_n)$ form a Markov chain, why or why not:
I get the following: Since $(S_n)$ is a Markov chain,

$$ 
\begin{eqnarray*}
P(Z_{n+1}=z_{n+1} |Z_n=z_n,\dots, Z_1=z_1) &=&P(S_{n+1}=z_{n+1}-z_n |S_n=z_n-z_{n-1},\dots, S_1=z_1)\\
&=& P(S_{n+1}=z_{n+1}-z_n|S_n=z_n-z_{n-1})\\
\end{eqnarray*}
$$ 
So it seems like the Markov condition shouldn't hold for $Z_n$, but I'm having difficulties coming up with a counter example.

Comment: If you concentrate on just $S_1,S_2$ and $S_3$ it shouldn't be difficult to write down a counterexample.

Comment: Here's my attempt: Let $X_k\sim Bernoulli(1/2)$, then $S_n\sim Bin(n,1/2)$ $$P(Z_3=2|Z_2=1,Z_1=0)=P(S_3=1|S_2=1,S_1=0) = P(S_3=1|S_2=1)=1/2$$ However, $$\begin{eqnarray*}P(Z_3=2|Z_2=1)&=&P(S_3=1|S_1+S_2=1)\\ &=&\frac{1}{2}P(S_3=1|S_2=0,S_1=1)  + \frac{1}{2}P(S_3=1|S_2=1,S_1=1)\\
&=&\frac{1}{2}P(S_3=1|S_2=0)  + \frac{1}{2}P(S_3=1|S_2=1)\\
&=& 1/2
\end{eqnarray*}
$$.

Comment: Good start. $S_2=0,S_1=1$ is not possible in your example. And $S_3=1,S_2=1,S_1=1$ is same as $X_1=1,X_2=0,X_3=0$. So just finish the proof by computing all the conditional probabilites you have.